# how many Nested words on the length of the words within l are there?

Tags: computation-theory

how many Nested words on the length of the words within l are there?

Comment: Warum haben Sie Deutsch geschrieben?

Comment: weil die Übung auf Deutsch ist

Comment: Aber StackOverflow ist nur Englisch.

Comment: seriously .. are you gonna make a discussion over this!!